# Algorithm for division.

Tags: c++, algorithm

May be I am already reinventing the wheel.

Normally in C, if we have a=34 and b=5 we get a/b=6. But I need the same thing for 100 digit numbers. I wrote a class with name Int. which does a+b and a-b and a*b. (a,b,c are type Int)

I overloaded the operators << , >>, which will return number divided or multiplied with 10.

What is the best algorithm for division? (assuming I store numbers as strings with base 10".

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not so sure introducing those semantics on the bit shift operators is such a good idea.

Comment: Funny, I've implemented a bignum class myself a while ago and i did exact same thing, used << and >> to multiply and divide by 10^n.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you should consult https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_%28digital%29, specifically the section on [large integer methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_%28digital%29#Large_integer_methods).

Answer (score 1):

You're reinventing the wheel.  See: http://gmplib.org/